# I want to parse web site using Python script which uses google sign in

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Some website uses google sign in, I am not able to parse such website. Help me with your valuable suggestion.
I am using python library utillib2, BeautifulSoup.
If some uses google sing in to login Quora, than I want to parse his details like what question he put up on the site and what is the response on the question.

Answer (score 0):

You've gotta be specific, post code links anything that can explain your question. 
We're not mind readers, so please when you post a question make your request detailed.

Comment: If any one uses gmail to login to Quora . Than how some one parse his details like what question he puts up on the site, what is the response.

Comment: Guessing that you're using BeautifulSoup and urllib requests.
Learn about GET and POST HTTP requests and then how can you implement them into your code.

Also, there's a lot of things going on when you're logging in, not just Login once and that's it, 
There are cookies that you have to keep ( store ) - That's put simply like an identification that you are you. *Therefore whever you request (Post or Get ) you're gonna have to say to their website Hey here's a cookie I'm ME !

Comment: Fuse : Thanks for your advice. Could you tell me any online source which can tell me all things which are going in the back while we login. This question was specific to google sign in  which is used by other website for login purpose.

Comment: Sorry, I can't name any online instances at this moment.
The best way is to find an already build open source code that you can use (or import functions from it ) and just work of that kind of 'framework'.
I.E. Site that uses google login, How to web scrape.
Or something along those lines, I personally haven't done it myself, therefore, I can't speak about it but I just got introduced with 'python selenium' by Fuego and others. 
This library simulates a web-browser, research it ( I can't help you much because I'm myself an entry student of said)